# Are crash reports meaningful when using RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, rx-swift

I am using Crashlytics from Fabric.io to manage a crash reports from an app.

I am considering to add RxSwift into new project but have doubt if a crash reports would be meaningful? Any experience ?

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for a solution for this right now.
As per my experience so far;

I have been using RXSwift in my project.
I have written 1 binding function and inside this added multiple PublishSubject's to listen button events.

When the crash happens from any of PublishSubject callbacks, Crashlytics seems to show only main binding function as crash reported function name which is actually useless information for me to catch the crash.. :(

If any solution for this from anyone, they are always welcome..